# IONIC apk is not working properly in mobile and emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, angular7

Hi guys I have generated one apk of my ionic angular app and when I run it on mobile device I am not able to type any text in text field. app works perfect locally.

So, can anyone suggest what related this problem is ??

Comment: Can you show a snippet your entry code? So that I can try to help you

Comment: @felipe-xst thanks for replying, actually it was my bad, disable=false property for all  <ion-input> solve the problem.